# What the difference between enum with string values and string type union in typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, types, enums, unions

When I need in typescript code a variable which has predefined set of values, I have two ways to achieve it - using enum or using union.

For example we have a button with different variants - primary, secondary, tertiary.

I can achieve it using enum:

```
enum Variant {
 Primary = "PRIMARY",
 Secondary = "SECONDARY",
 Tertiary = "TERTIARY"
}

const props = defineProps({
 variant: {
  type: String as PropType<Variant>
 }
})

<MyButton :variant="Variant.Primary" />
```

or I can achieve the same using union:

```
type Variant = "PRIMARY" | "SECONDARY" | "TERTIARY";

const props = defineProps({
 variant: {
  type: String as PropType<Variant>
 }
})

<MyButton :variant="PRIMARY" />
```

What's the difference between these two ways? Which way is more preferable? When I should use enum and when I should use union?

Comment: Enums provide a speaking name when your values are "coded", abbrevations or otherwise unintuitive, like `enum Variant { Primary = "a7", Secondary = "wb", Tertiary = "q2"}` plus you can annotate each value with documentation. But imo. the JS object they construct is a mess. *(Check out [const enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#const-enums) which compile completely away)* Unions are simpler. But if you don't have meaningful (speaking) values you'll likely make mistakes/introduce errors.

Comment: @thomas But I can even use `enum Variant {
 Primary,
 Secondary,
 Tertiary
}` so, it will use numbers as values and then I don't see any advantages of enum anymore. Relating your mention about mistakes when using unions - typescript performs type checks, and  if you will pass a wrong union value, then you will know about it before runtime step. Does it mean for the case in the topic unions will be preferred?

Comment: What number has `Secondary`? 2 right? **second**ary. Well, it's `1` in your enum and `Primary` is `0`. How long until you'll mix up the numbers, write a `2 (Tertiary)` when meaning `Secondary (1)`? That's the kind of mistakes I'm talking about when you don't have meaningful speaking names/values, not issues with types. *"Does it mean for the case in the topic unions will be preferred?"* only as long as you use clear speaking values like: `type Variant = "primary" | "secondary" | "tertiary";` Don't be afraid to be verbose; it's you who'll have to come back and fix your errors.

Comment: @Thomas Why I need to write 2, when I can write Variant.Tertiary and Typescript compiler will translate it to 2 in the runtime. Yes, it will be 2 in the runtime, but it is not a big deal how it is presented in the runtime while I can get type checks before my code is ran.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are beneficial when you want to provide a set of named values with explicit mappings. They are especially useful when the values represent options or configurations with specific meanings.

Unions are preferred when you have a simple set of values that don't require explicit naming. They are more lightweight and flexible, making them suitable for cases where you need to combine different types into one.